# Vue.js testing: props validation,how to test Vue console.error log with JEST

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, validation, vue.js, jestjs

During testing my new VueJS project with Jest I encountered problem caused by props validation.

All of my tests that has proper mocked data, pass the validator from component.

I would like to test situation when I mock `wrong data` and pass it to the component. I know that when the `validator` from component return `false`, `vue.common.js` console.error this:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:576
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "SOMETHING".
```

I would like to catch this error in my Jest test, but none of methods below I've tried work for me:

1. Using `spyOn(console, 'error')` and then `except(spy.calls.mostRecent()).toHaveBeenCalled()`.
2. Registering `console.*` in globals like this `global.console {...}`

I have no idea what should I try now or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for the answers, cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Solved:

I had to use my wrapper.vm object, something like this:

`expect(wrapper.vm.$options.props.YOUR_PROPS_OBJECT.validator(YOUR_WRONG_PROPS)).toBe(false);`

Answer (score 1):

One more way to deal with `validator` testing:

the component can be used directly, for instance, if the the component, being tested is named `App` and the property name is `p` then

```
expect(App.props.p.validator(arg)).toBe(res)
```

is the test for it.